Getting index out of bounds error in leetcode when I'm not out of bounds
I tried to solve an easy leecode question and I keep getting index out of bounds error, when I try the same solution on visual studio I dont get this error.
Here is the question and the code (I am failing a example 3):

Here is my code:
def merge(nums1, m, nums2, n ):
        """
        Do not return anything, modify nums1 in-place instead.
        """

        i1 = 0
        i2 = 0
        tmp = 0
        while i1 < n + m :
            if nums1[i1] == 0:
                nums1[i1] = nums2[i2]
                i1+=1
                i2+=1

            elif nums1[i1] <= nums2[i2]:
                i1 += 1
            else:
                tmp = nums2[i2]
                nums2[i2] = nums1[i1]
                nums1[i1] = tmp
                i1 += 1

It says Im out of bounds on this line: nelif nums1[i1] <= nums2[i2]: 
But I never reach this line because at this point I am out of the loop.
The error:
Runtime Error
IndexError: list index out of range
                      ~~~~~^^^^
    elif nums1[i1] <= nums2[i2]:
Line 16 in merge (Solution.py)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ret = Solution().merge(param_1, param_2, param_3, param_4)
Line 58 in _driver (Solution.py)
    _driver()
Line 70 in <module> (Solution.py)


Your code operates on TWO lists, nums1, nums2. But your code only checks for "valid range" for i1, the index that you use to access nums1. So, the real lesson here: when you are a newbie in a programming language - trust the messages. When the message tells you that one of your indexes is out of range, then that is your problem. Meaning: look at your indexces then (all of them) and look where something gets indexed.

To add to what @GhostCat said, print your indices when testing your code; additionnally, no need for tmp: Python allows swapping variables with a, b = b, a; furthermore, swapping values between nums1 and nums2 seems a bad idea: won't it break the non-decreasing clause of nums2?

@GhostCat I added 'and i2 < n' to this line and it did the trick. The only thing that I dont understand is why it worked perfectly on vs code?

Try to merge [10, 0, 0] and [1, 2] and see how well it works ;)

@Swifty yes you are right.

Instead of swapping values between list1 and list2, you could try inserting the value from nums2 into nums1; but this operation has a complexity of O(m), so it's not optimal in terms of efficiency.

3 thing to consider
The condition i1 < n + m in the while loop doesn't account for the fact that nums1 might be filled with zeros at the end.
There's no check to ensure i2 doesn't go out of bounds for nums2.
The logic assumes that all elements in nums1 that need to be replaced are zero, which may not be the case.
The swapping logic can lead to incorrect ordering.
Hope this will help to get more focused on solution

Here's a fixed version of your method; we bound i2 too, and insert values from nums2 into nums1. Note that, due to the complexity of list.insert(), the average complexity of this algorithm will be O(mn).
def merge(nums1, m, nums2, n):
    """
    Do not return anything, modify nums1 in-place instead.
    """

    i1 = 0
    i2 = 0
    while i1 < n + m and i2 <n:
        if nums1[i1] == 0:
            nums1[i1] = nums2[i2]
            i1 += 1
            i2 += 1

        elif nums1[i1] <= nums2[i2]:
            i1 += 1
        else:
            nums1.insert(i1, nums2[i2])
            nums1.pop()
            i1 += 1
            i2 += 1

Example:
a = [4, 10, 11, 0, 0]
b = [1, 10]
merge(a, 3, b, 2)
print(a)
# [1, 4, 10, 10, 11]

Here's another version that makes a copy of nums1, then fills nums1 with the relevant values from nums1 and nums2. This one runs in O(m+n).
def merge2(nums1, m, nums2, n):
    """
    Do not return anything, modify nums1 in-place instead.
    """

    i1 = 0
    i2 = 0
    source = nums1[:m]
    while i1 < m and i2 <n:
        if source[i1] <= nums2[i2]:
            nums1[i1 + i2] = source[i1]
            i1 += 1
        else:
            nums1[i1 + i2] = nums2[i2]
            i2 += 1
    if i1 < m:
        nums1[i1 + i2:] = source[i1:]
    else:
        nums1[i1 + i2:] = nums2[i2:]

